# How to override library classes in the child theme?

Tags: frameworks

I have a parent theme, There is a class for an external library included in the theme I want to override with a child theme.
Is there any way to do that?

The class path looks like that `/classes/themex.woo.php` and it's called by `require_one` function.

EDIT: Code Sample

I have these three files

- core/config.php
- core/ThemexCore.php
- core/modules/ThemexWoo.php

In `core/config.php`

```
$config = array (

    //Theme Modules
    'modules' => array(
        'ThemexShop',
        'ThemexWoo',
        'ThemexFacebook',
    );
```

In `core/ThemexCore.php`

```
class ThemexCore {
     public static $modules;

     public function __construct($config) {

        self::$modules=$config['modules'];
        $this->initModules();
     }

     public function initModules() {

        foreach(self::$modules as $module) {

            //require class
            $file=substr(strtolower(implode('.', preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $module))), 1);
            require_once(THEMEX_PATH.'classes/'.$file.'.php');

            //init module
            if(method_exists($module, 'init')) {
                call_user_func(array($module, 'init'));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I cropped just the necessary code, to make the context, now what I want to do is to extend or override the `core/modules/ThemexWoo.php` file in my child theme.

Comment: Waseem, please ask at the frameworks support routes. There is no chance anyone will know that.

Comment: @kaiser I edited the question in order to make it a general question about overriding external libraries included in parent themes.

Comment: You can simply extend the class to modify it as needed

Comment: I reopened it for now. It's not really on topic, but that question surely comes up with one or another framework. Still, I'd appreciate having a link so we can take a real world example when answering that. Do you have one for us?

Comment: Also please add and show us your use case (in an [edit]). Extending might not be possible in every scenario.

Comment: @kaiser I edited the question and included a code sample.

Comment: Can you define the config array yourself? In other words: Can you use a different class?